# How can I use async logging in flink docker

Tags: log4j, apache-flink

I'm running flink through docker containers
using my `log4j.properties` set to debug level.

I tried adding `-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector` but doesn't seem to work

I'm guessing that I need to use a new version of log4j. not sure how to do this

Comment: If by newer version of Log4j you mean log4j2, then it can be problematic as Flink is still using log4j 1.x.x

Comment: You can see from where it's trying to get log4j properties on initialization, maybe it can help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: log4j properties also depend on which client you use to run: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html#configuring-log4j